# codeigniter photo upload no error warning on non allowed types files

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, photo

Here is upload function:

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './photos/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']  = 1024 * 2;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = true;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    //$this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("photo_data"))
    {
        $this->error = true;
        $this->response = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->upload->data();
        $this->response = "Photo successfully changed.";
    }

    $array = array(
        'error' => $this->error,
        'response' => $this->response
    );

    return $array;
```

However in order to test that it doesnt allow file types except the one that i allow i renamed a video to .jpg and tried to upload it...

It didnt proceed but it didnt also send an error message... i suppose somwhere in the `upload class` `returns false`... any idea how to make sure it sends a message to the user first?

Answer (score 0):

How are you printing the errors in your view? The method returning false somewhere in the upload class is the one you already checked for FALSE, i.e. `$this->upload->do_upload()`

You should pass those errors to a view, if you want the site to display them:

This assumes the code you posted is from a controller:

```
$array = array(
        'error' => $this->error,
        'response' => $this->response
    );

$this->load->view('upload_view',$array);
//instead of returning, as "return" in a controller makes little sense. If you're inside a model, then, get the returned value in a controller and pass it to a view.
```

In your "upload_view.php" view file:

```
<div class="<?php $error? 'error' : 'success';?>"><?php echo $response;?></div>
```

Comment: thats how i print the errors: <?php if (isset($upload_data["error"])): ?><div class="error_warning" style="display:block;"><?php echo $upload_data["response"]; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
the thing is that it doesnt get into any if conditional if the file is .jpg renamed from a video in any case....

Comment: Where do you set the $upload_data variable? I don't see it in the code you posted...Sidenote (and unrelated): you're passing the $config twice, stick either pass it as second argument while loading the library or using initialize, not both

Comment: its in the User class array being sent into the view so i echo the errors if i got any after upload is complete